# input email con default @ jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Necesito crear un input email que mantenga por default el caracter "@" y sin que se pueda borrar ademas de oder escribir delante del "@" y detras de este ?, se puede realizar esto ? muchas gracias

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" id="myEmail" value="@">
```

Comment: Mantener lo podrías mantener pero no tendría mucho sentido, ya que el email no sigue un patrón tan certero como por ejemplo el de una fecha en la cual seria **__/__/__** y mantener los **/** sin embargo en el email no sabes la posición exacta del cursor en la cual deberá permanecer la **@**.

Comment: eso no lo había pensado , se puede mantener pero el la posición del cursor es el problema :/

Answer (score -1):

Este me sirve ami.

```js
$("input").keydown(function(e) {
    var oldvalue=$(this).val();
    var field=this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if(field.value.indexOf('@') !== 0) {
            $(field).val(oldvalue);
        } 
    }, 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" value="@" />
```

Comment: ¿existe la forma de escribir delante del "@"?, hasta el momento ese seria mi pero... :c

Comment: ¿No sería mejor trabajar con el evento **keyup** ó **change**?

Comment: @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar Si me das un rato te digo como

Comment: ok no problem gracias